# Deadlock / Access violation in my code even though I've mutually excluded it

Tags: c++, multithreading, exception, deadlock

So I'm trying to better understand multi threading and how deadlocks happen and how to avoid them so I put together a small piece of code. Basically I have two threads which share an int pointer.

Each thread both reads and writes from/to the value being pointed to.
When a thread writes (increases the value by 1), I lock a global mutex around it.
When it reads (couts it to console), I lock a global mutex around it.

Here's my code first of all:

```
    // DeadLockTest.cpp
    //

    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <thread>
    #include <mutex>
    using namespace std;

    void foo(int* p);
    void bar(int* p);

    mutex mut;

    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
            int x = 5;
            int* p = &x;

            thread first(bind(foo, p));
            thread second(bind(bar, p));

            first.join();
            second.join();
            cout << "threads done";
            cin.ignore();
            return 0;
    }

    void foo(int* p){
            int i = 0;
            while(1){
                    i++;
                    mut.lock();
                    *p++;
                    mut.unlock();

                    mut.lock();
                    cout << "foo: " << *p << endl;
                    mut.unlock();

            }
    }

    void bar(int* p){
            int i = 0;
            while(1){
                    i++;
                    mut.lock();
                    *p--;
                    mut.unlock();

                    mut.lock();
                    cout << "bar" << *p << endl;
                    mut.unlock();

            }
    }
```

I eventually get an exception:

> Unhandled exception at 0x008E608F in DeadLockTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x003B0000.

First things first, why am I getting the exception? I've mutually locked the resource from being accessed from the other thread. If I've done something wrong, this leads to another question. The exception always happens on the cout statement in foo, it never happens anywhere else (not even in the bar thread). Why only the foo thread and why only on the cout statement? What about when I decrease/increase the referenced value?

Second, should each thread be using its own mutex? Or is this okay to use a globally shared mutex? What would be the difference between the threads using their own mutex local to their scope rather than a globally shared mutex?

And third, if I have a condition on my threads so they don't run infinitely, why is it that:

```
cout << "threads done";
```

gets called after the two threads have finished? The two threads are run asynchronously, no?

Just trying to get a better understanding of this for the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried it on linux, compiling with `g++ -std=c++0x -pthread foo.cpp -o foo` and it segfaults here as well.

However, I just tried changing `*p++` and `*p--` to `(*p)++` and `(*p)--` and it worked!

The problem is that you're incrementing and decrementing the pointer instead of the value you're pointing to.  Try this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int i = 123;
  int *p;
  p = &i;

  cout << *p++ << endl;
  cout << *p++ << endl;
  cout << *p++ << endl;
  cout << *p++ << endl;
  cout << *p++ << endl;
}
```

The output is:

```
123
-166656888
32767
0
0
```

Now you'll understand that an access violation means that you're trying to access memory that you can't. Which indicates that you've got a pointer pointing to where you don't want it to.

So when you're doing `*p++` you're incrementing the pointer, and not the value. By dereferencing first, by doing `(*p)`, you make sure that it's the *value* and not the pointer that's changed.

Comment: Ah all right, it's all about precedence.
But what about the threads though? 

Why is it that "threads done" always (if you look at the bottom of my post) gets output after the threads are done? I thought threads were asynchronous. And also the mutex's. What's the difference between using a global mutex and using a mutex that's local to both the threads? Will both protect against access violations the same way?

Comment: You're explicitly joining the threads, which means you want to wait until they're done before proceeding. That's why the done message comes last -- your main thread is waiting for the others to finish (your threads never terminate, though). Try e.g. to run it with locking on the inc/dec part and not cout, you'll see they run async. Finally, try adding in main `cout.sync_with_stdio(false);`.

Comment: Hm all right. Well now I'm trying to enforce a deadlock for learning purposes. I removed the mutex locks/unlocks but I'm not getting a deadlock, why is this?
Or are deadlocks not really that common with this sort of code?

Comment: Well, it's easy to provoke race conditions at least (have N threads increment same variable by one M times, result should me M*N). For deadlocks, just make sure threads are waiting for each other (see a standard OS textbook).